# My html link only opens with open in new tab?

Tags: html, hyperlink

My code has been working fine before but since I added the onlick part, i can no longer access it on left click. I have to open it in new tab.

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault(); window.parent.postMessage('link_url:'+this.href,'*');" href="?redirect=Pro" class="btn btn-accept display-5" target="_blank">I AGREE</a>
```

I cant remove that part since I need it otherwise my other redirect links from another php file wouldnt work. If i remove it, I cant redirect properly. Kindly asking for advice on how to fix this so I can open with left click or at least automatically open in new tab on left click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason this can't just be a regular link anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the event.preventDefault Function from your HTML line. Because, 
This will prevent your events.

```
<a onclick="window.parent.postMessage('link_url:'+this.href,'*');" href="?redirect=Pro" class="btn btn-accept display-5" target="_blank">I AGREE</a>
```